# HTML in popover with angular-bootstrap 0.12.1 & Angular 1.2.x

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to have HTML inside a popover content.

It's possible with a specific directive on the next versions, but I need to use the 0.12.1 version of angular-bootstrap since I'm using Angular 1.2.28

Any idea how I could implement this ?

I'm using a simple case :

```
<button popover="{{ testData }}"
        popover-placement="bottom" 
        class="btn btn-icon btn-icon-sm btn-icon-default">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

With in js :

```
$scope.testData = "<b>Bold data</b>" + " Normal data " + " &lt;b&gt;Encoded bold data&lt;/b&gt;";
```

But obviously it's not working since HTML is not yet supported as popover content in this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, inspired from a plunker, it can be achieved by adding the following directives :

```
.directive("popoverHtmlUnsafePopup", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            content: "@",
            placement: "@",
            animation: "&",
            isOpen: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: "template/popover/popover-html-unsafe-popup.html"
    };
})

.directive("popoverHtmlUnsafe", ["$tooltip", function ($tooltip) {
    return $tooltip("popoverHtmlUnsafe", "popover", "click");
}])
```

With the template module :

```
angular.module("template/popover/popover-html-unsafe-popup.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("template/popover/popover-html-unsafe-popup.html",
    "<div class=\"popover {{placement}}\" ng-class=\"{ in: isOpen(), fade: animation() }\">\n" +
    "  <div class=\"arrow\"></div>\n" +
    "\n" +
    "  <div class=\"popover-inner\">\n" +
    "      <h3 class=\"popover-title\" ng-bind=\"title\" ng-show=\"title\"></h3>\n" +
    "      <div class=\"popover-content\" bind-html-unsafe=\"content\"></div>\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
 }]);
```